# How do I stored a date in my model?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, date, model

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 and MySql 5.5.37.  I have a model based on the following db table …

```
mysql> desc user_objects;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| object     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| day        | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| total      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In my controller, I’m trying to process parameters submitted from a form and so I use this …

```
def create
  @current_user = User.find(session["user_id"])
  …
  puts user_object_params
  @user_object = UserObject.new(user_object_params)
  puts @user_object.object 
  puts @user_object.day 
  puts @user_object.total
```

Even though the first “puts” line prints out “{"object"=>"3", "day"=>"02/28/2016", "total"=>"77"}”, the third puts line (“@user_object.day”) prints out nothing.  What do I need to do to get my date object created in my model via the “new” call?

**Edit:** Here is the definition of user_object in the file "./app/models/user_object.rb".

```
class UserObject < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :day, :presence => true
  validates_numericality_of :total
  validates :object, :presence => true

  def self.find_total_by_user_object_month_and_year(user_id, object, month, year)
    sum(:total, :conditions => ['user_id = ?', user_id, 'object = ?', object, 'month(day) = ?', month, 'year(day) = ?', year])
  end

  def self.find_total_by_user_object_and_year(user_id, object, year)
    sum(:total, :conditions => ['user_id = ?', user_id, 'object = ?', object, 'year(day) = ?', year])
  end

end
```

**Edit 2:** In response to the answer given, including this in my controller

```
  puts user_object_params[:day] 
  @user_object.day = user_object_params[:day]
  puts @user_object.day
```

Prints out "02/23/2016" for teh first "puts" but then nothing is printed for the second "puts."

Comment: do `@user_object.object` and `@user_object.total` have the correct values?

Comment: What is the class definition for UserObject and what is its responsibility?  Is that some sort of form object, or what is it?

Comment: If you successfully save a date in that column then everything you've done here should work.

Comment: I included the class definition for UserObject.  It is meant to mirror the database table I included.  And no, I cannot save teh date column successfully -- it saves as null.

Comment: If you can save the other fields (not sure you can - that's why I asked), I wonder if it's a finicky Ruby date formatting issue.

Comment: Hi, I suspect its a date formatting issue as well.  How do I tell Rails to accept things of a certain date format?  Rails seems pretty smart about stuff like this and that this kind of thing can be done with minimal coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to open an answer, but expect it will require some iteration.

Assuming `@user_object.object` and `@user_object.total` are behaving correctly (you need to confirm this), I suspect you're experiencing finicky Ruby Date (or related) problems.

Make sure that (a) `@user_object.day` is defined (in your migration) in the format that you want (are you storing a String, Date, or DateTime?) and that (b) `user_object_params[:day]` is formatted in a way that matches the type defined in your migration.

There are well-know subleties (read, differences) is how Ruby and Rails handle Dates and DateTimes. Maybe this is the root of your problem.

To convert a date string into a DateTime, you're going to have to do something like:

```
DateTime.strptime("06/18/2013", "%m/%d/%Y")
```

as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105617/converting-string-to-date-before-save-with-rails). So, possibly before doing `@user_object.new(user_object_params)`, you might need to do something like:

```
user_object_params[:day] = DateTime.strptime(user_object_params[:day], "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Fishing here, but thought it might help.

Comment: The column is dfeined in my migration like so: "t.date :day".  Regarding this, "user_object_params[:day] is formatted in a way that matches the type defined in your migration," I don't understand what you mean by this.  Can you give an example, preferably one taht uses the format, "%m/%d/%Y"?

Comment: Hi, Dave. I did give the example. See the strptime line above. Did you give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are getting the params correct, However to check if the issue is in the `UserObject.new(user_object_params)` part, what you can try is try to individually assign values

```
@user_object = UserObject.new
@user_object.object = user_object_params[:object]
@user_object.day = user_object_params[:day]
@user_object.total = user_object_params[:total]
```

and then try to print the values.

I have a feeling that the attribute `object` is conflicting with some rails internal attributes.

to test this, you can individually assign value except object attr. or remove the `object` key in the hash.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but still no dice.  THis line "@user_object.day = user_object_params[:day]" does not save the value of what is submitted.  This has something to do with the fact that my model's field is a date, right?  How do I tell Rails to accept the submitted date with a certain format?

Comment: how about manually change the format, something like `user_object_params[:day].gsub('/','-')`

Comment: Sure, I coudl give that a shot, but is that the Rails way?  It seems like tehre would be some setting somewhere that I coudl tell Rails waht my date format shoudl be.  Does such a setting exist?